# Не отправляется post запрос с токеном

Tags: reactjs, .net, axios

никак не могу решить вопрос с отправкой post запроса к сервер Net core.

```
const PostClient = (e: any) => {

httpModule.post("Client/PostClient", {
  Name: client1.name,
  Phone: client1.phone,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`
  }
}
)
.then((responce) => console.log(responce.data))
.catch((error) => console.log(error)) }
```

Возникает 401 Unauthorized. Как решить проблему? Спасибо!

Comment: Видимо проблема с jwt, или с ендпоинтом на сервере. Есть возможность показать ендпоинт маршрута "Client/PostClient"?

Comment: EnableCors(origins: "http://www.example.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]

Я чуть позже попробую корсы ему любые включить